# Does a proof by induction have to explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction?

Tags: proofs, induction

I teach high school math.

Some of my colleagues insist that a proof by induction should explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction, i.e. it must include the words "by the principle of mathematical induction" or words of equivalent meaning.

Others say that (given a proposition $H_n$) it is enough to show that the base case is true and that $H_k\implies H_{k+1}$; it is not necessary to explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction.

Solutions in the mark schemes for the exams (IB and A-level) are inconsistent: sometimes they explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction, sometimes they do not, and sometimes they refer to it in brackets (indicating that it is optional).

If a proof by induction has to explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction, then do proofs using the pigeonhole principle have to explicitly refer to the pigeonhole principle? Do proofs by contradiction have to explicitly refer to the principle of proof by contradiction (if there is such a thing)?

Possibly relevant: [Why does induction have to be an axiom?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2817147/398708)

Comment: I don't know what "should" and "have to" mean in this context. There are no official rules for what constitutes a proof or not. They are written to convince an audience. The question that's relevant is whether requiring your students to do this helps them learn the material better and avoid mistakes.

Comment: One way to approach this is to ask what professional mathematicians do. If I open up a math journal and see a proof by induction, will it assume that I will recognize that it is a proof by induction or will it have verbiage such as "by the principle of induction"?

Comment: Isn't 'by the principle of mathematical induction' needed only when various steps have been skipped? If induction does have to be an axiom, where is the rather complicated expression shown by that link included in the list of axioms?

Comment: If a student doesn't refer to the pigeonhole principle explicitly, how do you know that they were using the pigeonhole principle at all? Likewise, if a proof ends with "and thus 1 = 0" and doesn't conclude "and this shows by proof by contradiction that square root of 2 cannot be rational", how are you going to know that it was a proof by contradiction and what it is that was proven?

Comment: Also, the most important thing here is probably how consistent *you*, the teachers, are with your students. If you explicitly tell them that proofs are expected to use the word "induction" explicitly, then there is no surprise. But if you're sometimes very strict about it and sometimes don't care, because you're following inconsistent mark schemes blindly, then the pedagogical impact will be awful for the students.

Comment: Can you Post some examples? Can you show how you'd use proof by induction, without referring to it?

Comment: When I learned induction at high school, you needed to use a very precise and long phrase at the end of the proof, something along the lines of "Since P(0) is true, and whenever P(k) is true, P(k+1) is true, then by the principle of mathematical induction, P(n) is true for all n" (and this was over two decades ago, and I've never used it since). If you didn't include this precise phrase, you lost marks, regardless of whether the proof was correct or not. Personally, I'd love to see the death of the phrase "principle of mathematical induction", in favour of plain "induction".

Comment: It's important to know that the hardest part about teaching induction is that it cannot be proved from simpler principles, it is literally an axiom of how natural numbers are formally defined. I'm always honest with students and tell them about this fact. I tell them it is indeed subtle, and that the recognition that this is actually such an axiom was only codified near the 19th century, a loooong time after people have been using numbers for all sorts of things.

Comment: When *teaching*, it would definitely be a good idea to mention induction explicitly, every time it is used. It will help students familiarise themselves with the notion. However when examining, or grading coursework, one should not penalise students for not mentioning induction *by name*, if their answers, otherwise, use induction arguments correctly.

Comment: @Stef It is not about "blindly" following markschemes. Students can get a surprise if I (as a teacher) consistently tell students that they do not have to refer to the principle explicitly, but at the end of their two year study (in the IBDP system) they get a centralized exam, where examiners do require it (just because in that particular year they felt it that way). Of course, this can be avoided with consistently requiring an explicit reference.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I cannot post an example in a comment, but here is an outline. Step 1: checking P(0). Step 2: proving that P(k) implies P(k+1). Step 3: "Hence, P(n) is true for all nonnegative integer n"

Comment: @FerencBeleznay Thanks and while it's clear that Comment uses it, are you suggesting it refers to the principle?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I am not sure I understood your comment correctly, but in my previous reply the word "hence" in step 3 means (at least in IBDP examination markschemes) that the work done in step 1 and step 2 imply somehow the claim in step 3. This "somehow" is the principle of mathematical induction. With the wording in my previous reply we use it without explicitly referring to it. If I change the wording in step 3 to "Hence, by the principle of mathematical induction, P(n) is true for all nonnegative integer n", then we use it with an explicit reference.

Comment: I believe it's very interesting to realise that "induction" comes from "indūcere", which means "to lead someone inside (a building or a room)". I guess it means that the person does not accompany his guest inside. From there you have the physical meaning "to cause an effect inside something (without actually going inside)", but how does the word "induction" gets it mathematical meaning?

Comment: @Dominique According to the *OED*, induction (as meaning generalization from particulars) came into English in the 1500s from Aristotle, *epagoge* (*epi*+*agoge*, on+leading, or leading on from particulars to the general), via Cicero's translation as *inductio*. Possibly mathematics borrowed the term from induction in natural science, which had become prominent due to Francis Bacon (*Nova Organum*, 1620). The phrase "mathematical induction" first appears in an article on induction by De Morgan in the *Penny Cyclopedia* (1838), which first calls it "successive induction," a better name, imo.

Comment: @DavidRoberts "...the hardest part about teaching induction is that it cannot be proved from simpler principles, it is literally an axiom..." If this is your experience then it's not my place to argue, but my experience is that induction is hard to teach because people simply don't get it--maybe because it seems circular. Once they catch on, I think it's easy for them to accept that there should be such a principle. That the principle doesn't follow from the other axioms of Peano arithmetic and needs to be assumed is an interesting point about formalization, but not a barrier to understanding,

Comment: @WillOrrick What I mean is that you cannot prove to students *why* induction is a legitimate argument from things they already know. In my experience students are not certain about how it's ok, because we cannot prove why it's ok. It's just presented as a fait accompli, which is more or less is. By saying "people just don't get it" only sweeps the *reason* they don't get it under a different rug. By saying "maybe it seems circular", you are closer to the mark. I think students want a *reason* why it works. I don't mean from the other axioms of Peano Arithmetic, but even a pre-formal argument.

Comment: That said, the biggest hurdle at a nuts-and-bolts level is knowing what it means to prove an implication (that is, the single step P(n) => P(n+1)). But that is an independent issue from have a reason to "believe in" induction (as in, to have a well-founded trust that it really does work).

Comment: @DavidRoberts For a "pre-formal" argument would you accept a metamathematical argument? You have an algorithm for constructing (increasingly long) valid proofs of $P(2)$, $P(3)$, and so on. So for any $n$ one cares to ask about, there's a valid proof for that $n$, which you know how to construct. This seems convincing to me. The subtle point is that reasoning within the system does't allow you to go from this algorithm for constructing valid proofs for each $n$ to the universally quantified  statement $\forall n P(n)$. But I don't think that is what bothers most students.

Comment: @WillOrrick I don't claim it consciously bothers them. But the fact we *cannot* give an argument/proof of how induction works/why it's justified means suddenly students are faced with a fact that cannot be treated in the same way as everything they'd seen up to that point (well, more or less: even addition and multiplication are informally justified by recourse to manipulables and counting etc).

Comment: Thanks Ferenc and doesn't it seem that as long as there are enough doubts out there for queries such as Dan and Stef's to case so much comment in a place like this, some people would be helped and no-one  hindered by always using 'by induction', with or without a leading 'Hence'?

Comment: @WillOrrick "Maybe because it seems circular" — that is certainly one of the stumbling blocks, in my experience. Students yet unused to proofs lose sight of quantifiers. The student has to prove $P(n)$. So they assume $P(n)$ or $P(k)$ according to the induction step formula. Now they have to prove $P(k+1)$. Since they know $P(k)$ is true, why not plug $k+1$ into $P(k)$ and get $P(k+1)$ immediately, just as they've always been allowed to do in algebra class? [That's the student's question; I know the answer.]

Comment: @DavidRoberts I thought I could leave this alone, but I'm finding I cannot. If a student ignorant of induction tells us it's clear that $\sum_{i=1}^n1=n$, are we to instruct them that it's not clear and that if they believe it to be clear they must be confused about something? If yes, what educational purpose is being served by doing so? I can see a student with a thirst to know mathematics feeling chastened and going off to learn what they need to know in order to grasp the issue at hand, which for some might take a long time. But I can also see a student being turned off of mathematics.

Comment: @WillOrrick For me, it is fine if a student tells that it is clear that $\sum_{i=1}^n 1=n$, and I would not instruct them that it is not clear. However, from a student who is interested in mathematics in a way that is more than a procedural application of rules, I would expect to at least think it over if I ask "How would you prove it?" I would not expect a proof (that is the procedural part, if they know for example induction). I would expect a realization that there are things we accept without proof.

Comment: @FerencBeleznay I'm sure it's not what you intended, but I find the description, "interested in mathematics in a way that is more than a procedural application of rules", to be dismissive of the mathematical insight of ordinary people. What if, rather than confessing that they have no proof, they attempt an explanation? What if, perhaps of their own initiative, perhaps with some prodding, the student comes up with the idea that 1+1+1 is the number following 1+1 and that 1+1+1+1 is the number following 1+1+1 and that they can build up the general rule in that way? How are they procedurally...

Comment: ...following rules in a way that a student who has the--historically contingent--piece of knowledge that arithmetic has been axiomatized in a particular way isn't? Really what I was reacting to with these comments was David Roberts' surprising assertion that there is no pre-formal understanding of induction.

Comment: @WillOrrick You are really reading things in my comment which is not there. It is a fact that there are students who continuously ask for rules. I meet them all the time. I am not saying this as a judgement, just stating it. I am perfectly OK with this. When I ask "how would you prove it", I am not asking for a proof, I am giving an opportunity for them to think deeper. If they don't want to do it, that is fine. What you are describing is the approach of a student, who is interested beyond procedures. This is not in contradiction to what I was saying. On the contrary. ...

Comment: ... In my comment I do say that the procedural part is the formal application of the method of induction. What you are describing is a student who discovers an important intuitive property of natural numbers (namely that they can build up the general rule this way), which they take for granted.

Comment: @FerencBeleznay I apologize for putting words in your mouth. I agree with much of what you say, especially regarding interactions with students. I suspect there are some philosophical differences between us having to do with shades of meaning of words like "know", "prove", and "understand", and with the relative emphases placed on intuition and formalism, in particular as they relate to teaching.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The appropriate level of granularity for a proof depends on the audience.

- If you're taking an "Intro to Proofs" class and your homework is to do some proofs by induction, then yeah, you will be expected to state when, where, and how you use the principle of mathematical induction. You should explicitly label the base case, the inductive hypothesis, etc. Not because your grader needs that information to follow your proof, but because the whole point of the homework is to demonstrate that you know this stuff. (Likewise, if you're teaching an "Intro to Proofs" class then obviously you need to label all those steps in your example proofs to provide proper scaffolding for students.)
- If you're a full-blown mathematician who is writing a research paper, then your audience already knows this stuff like the back of their hand, so most of it doesn't need to be said explicitly. Sure, it will make the reading a little gentler if you precede the inductive proof with "By induction, ...", and that would probably be a nice thing to do for your audience, but you're not going to lose any other research mathematician in your audience if you omit the explicit reference to induction, and nobody is going to question your understanding of induction because you didn't explicitly label something (you'd have to make a legitimate and egregious error in the basic logic for that to happen).

Your case sounds closer to the first one, so I would say sure, as long as your colleagues tell their students what features of the induction proof they are required to explicitly state/label, it's appropriate for them to expect a student's induction proof to include those features.

... though if they're reading a math research publication and claiming that it should be edited to include the include the words "by the principle of mathematical induction", then that's a different story ;)

Comment: The other fun one is that (for the simple proofs you would encounter in precalculus or other "intro to proofs" settings) you can do induction [without even using the induction axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle). (You still need it for second-order logic shenanigans, but the average student who is being introduced to induction will have *no* understanding of that.)

Comment: Even for a research paper, it's often worth writing explicitly that a proof is by induction, because just using that word allows you to be more concise and skip every boring part of the proof and keep only the most interesting part (if any).

Comment: " the whole point...is to demonstrate that you know this stuff" — This is how I explain such requirements to students, too. I appreciate that your answers are centered on (the assessment of) the learning goals at hand.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give a reference to a research paper that does not mention "by induction" when they apply a proof by induction?

Comment: @FerencBeleznay No, I don't have a reference. I'm sure it's vastly more common to mention "by induction" when applying a proof by induction. I would do that myself, and I would appreciate if the author of a paper I'm reading did that -- my only claim is that "by induction" is not something that *must* be in such a proof, even if it pretty much always is.

Comment: Well, unlike high school textbooks, research papers follow the Claim/Proof/Qed format. If a claim says "for all $n$ $P(n)$", and the proof only includes the justification of $P(0)$ and the implication $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$, then in my opinion it is not complete. It must have something extra. Either starting the proof referencing induction, or ending the proof with "hence, $\forall n P(n)$" (with or without the explicit reference to induction).

Comment: @FerencBeleznay: Regarding a reference where a proof by induction is given without mentioning the word "induction", see for instance the proof of equality of (11.9) on page 170 in [this book](https://zbmath.org/1420.47001) or the proof of Lemma 3.3 in [this article](https://zbmath.org/1454.46040). Another nice formulation can be found in the proof of Proposition 2.2 "(ii)$\Rightarrow$(i)" of [this article](https://zbmath.org/1327.58032): there the authors say "by iteration" to give a brief intuitive description of what is formally an argument by induction.

Comment: @FerencBeleznay: Re your [last comment](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/27174/does-a-proof-by-induction-have-to-explicitly-refer-to-the-principle-of-mathemati/27179#comment72379_27175), I'm having difficulties to understand what you mean by "the proof is not complete". For a mathematician, a proof is complete if they can understand it from what is written down. Not writing down "by induction" or "hence the claim follows for all n" typically won't prevent readers from understanding a proof. Sometimes it might have a (minor) impact on the readability of the proof, though.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Unfortunately I do not have access to see the content of the article you sent, but thank you for the link. When I say "not complete", that is just what I mean. There is a logical gap, which the reader probably can fill in, but nevertheless, it is there.

Comment: @FerencBeleznay: The last reference I linked is also available on arXiv (the former two unfortunately not). [...]

Comment: [...] Re non-complete proofs and logical gaps: You seem to assume that there were a standard and universally agreed upon definition of what constitutes a complete proof or a logical gap. But, at least outside of formal logic, this is not the case and the issue is handled more pragmatically. As I said, mathematicians don't determine whether a proof is complete by somekind of formal definition of completeness - but by whether they are able to understand and confirm the arguments from what is written down. In particular, whether a proof is considered complete depends on the audience/readership.

Answer (score 6):

A blast from the past comment, for the consolation of your students, of a mathematician being marked down by one of the most influential mathematicians of his day:

John Wallis in his *Arithmetica Infinitorum* (1656) in Prop. XIX
examines the sum of squares up to $n^2$ divided by $n^2(n+1)$.
He computes them for $n$ up to $n=6$ and proclaims
that by way of induction ("*per modum inductionis*"),
that the sum is given by
$${\,0\;+\,1\,+\,4\;+\cdots+n^2 \over n^2+n^2+n^2+\cdots+n^2}={1\over3}+{1\over6n} \,.$$
Wallis is the first written source to use the word "induction"
to describe and justify the proof of a proposition.
Wallis used his form of induction frequently.
Wallis was criticized, but he defended his method.
Jacob Bernoulli suggested that one of Wallis's proofs could be
improved by showing how the $n+1$ case followed from the case for $n$ —
an explicit statement of the induction step.
Here is Wallis defending his method in 1685, *A Treatise of Algebra*,
Ch.78, p.298:

> Those propositions in my Arithmetick of Infinites, are (some of them) demonstrated by way of Induction: Which is plain, obvious, and easy; and where things proceed in a clear regular Order, (as here they do,) very satisfactory, (to any who hath not a mind to cavil;) and shews the true natural investigation. Which to me, is much more grateful and agreeable, than the Operose Apagogical Demonstrations, (by reducing to Absurdities or Impossibilities,) which some seem to affect;...

Long before the Principle of Mathematical Induction had been formalized, there was controversy over how pedantically formal proofs should be.

Answer (score 5):

I am (one of the) colleagues David refers to in his post. The reason I am doing this lies in some of the answers/comments posted here already. For example, Humberto sais: "While technically it may be sufficient to show that the base case holds and the inductive step follows (Hk ⟹ Hk+1), ...". My question is why? In my opinion, the answer is "because of the principle of mathematical induction". In my opinion, this is not at all obvious. Nothing else (except the well-ordering principle) implies this. This is why (in my opinion) it needs to be stated. Otherwise students may think that this is obviously some consequence of some theorem(s) that mathematicians who deal with the formal foundation of mathematics proved already. I may be wrong, but I think that it is not. It is an intuitive belief that cannot be proven from the other properties we take for granted (the axioms, if we want to use more formal language). So, back to Humberto's comment, I do not think that technically it is enough to check the base case and the induction step. Intuitively I agree it is enough, but technically we need a concluding statement (with or without the explicit reference to the principle).

Whether we want to insist on students mentioning the point where they use the principle is of course a matter of opinion. An example is posted in [Grade on proving |$a_1 +a_2+...+a_n| \le |a_1|+|a_2|+... +|a_n|$](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/20666/grade-on-proving-a-1-a-2-a-n-le-a-1a-2-a-n/20675#comment56005_20675) . In this post the student used practically an inductive proof, but instead of formally following the steps (required by most IB and A-level high school markschemes) the student wrote "repeating this ...". He clearly understood the intuition, but not what induction is about. It is not just about formally using a certain method. It is also about why to use the method instead of intuitive arguments.

Comment: "Otherwise students may think that this is obviously some consequence of some theorem(s) that mathematicians who deal with the formal foundation of mathematics proved already."  No students in school are thinking about what mathematicians dealing with formal foundations of mathematics are doing.

Comment: Counterpoint: should proofs explicitly label each use of _modus ponens_

Comment: To play devil's advocate, would you accept the phrase "by induction", rather than "by the principle of **mathematical** induction"? Are your students likely to confuse the induction they are doing in proofs in mathematics with [induction as used in the philosophical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning)?

Comment: @KCd In the IB (international Baccalaureate) all students learn something called "Theory of Knowledge", where they discuss the ways of knowing in different disciplines. When discussing mathematics, they do talk about axiomatic foundations. Some students of course are satisfied with the approach of "give me a formula/method and I use it", but there are plenty who do ask the question "why can we do this?". Probably not in the way I worded it, but there are high school students who are genuinely interested in why things work, even in theoretical mathematics.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, I would accept "by induction". I think that the students who heard of inductive reasoning would know the difference (and probably would emphasise mathematical without being asked), the others would not even know that there are different meanings of the word "induction". I myself did not meet any student so far who asked me about this.

Comment: When I require special incantations from my students, I contextualize them. "We are writing this for clarity. You might not find it in professional writing, but for this course I will require it, as it helps to demonstrate your understanding." I think in this instance, you are being a bit silly because the cognitive traps you are apparently avoiding seem implausible in a novice, but by the same token, I don't see the harm as long as you do not teach that the statement affects the validity of the proof (it clearly doesn't), but is instead a component of how you ensure that students understand.

Comment: @BenI. Suppose a students argues the following way: Step 1: P(0) is true; Step 2: P(k) implies P(k+1). If they stop here, the proof is incomplete. There are quite a few students who do this. Did they understand proof by induction? In my opinion, no. They partly understood (or rather follow) the structure, but they did not understand why it works. There are of course several students who add Step 3: Hence, P(n) is true for all n. This step is needed for completeness, not for clarity. If the add "by induction" to step 3, it indicates further understanding (the structure, and maybe the reason).

Answer (score 3):

Typically you want to name things. This makes them visible and something you can discuss. So, while teaching, you do want to say that this thing her is induction, so we have to remember to check the base case, and that from every case we can deduce the next one. If you do not name this thing, then it is likely that many students do not know what they should be paying attention to.

An exam requiring particular magical incantations seems silly, but if succeeding at them is important, then you should teach the magical incantations to the students. You may want to say that in general it is a good idea to say that you using induction, so that the reader is oriented, but whether it is called the principle of induction, or one just writes "By induction...", or explains the idea in the proof itself; not really essential.

So:

- Make the proof as easy to understand as possible.
- Tell students to use any magic words an exam requires *in that exam*.
- Writing like mathematics articles are written is not always a good idea, as many mathematics articles are poorly written, just like many academic texts in general. There are of course many good ideas there, too, but one has to think communication first, not just copy and paste expressions from other examples of the genre (mathematics research article or textbook).

Comment: The last one is more of a general note.

Answer (score 3):

In a pedagogical context I can see four types of situation where it may reasonably be required for students to explicitly state their use of the principle of mathematical induction:

1. If writing proofs by induction is part of the material being tested, students may be required to state its use explicitly.
2. If the material being tested itself distinguishes in a meaningful way between proofs that use induction and proofs that don't (e.g. a class covering different logical systems and what can/can't be proven in each), students may be required to state where any such proof uses the principle of mathematical induction explicitly.
3. If the students need to write proofs in an extremely standardized format (e.g. so that it can be automatically graded) they may be required to explicitly state whether or not the principle of mathematical induction is used.
4. If the students are generally not expected to already know the principle of mathematical induction and it is not part of the material covered in the class, then any student who does happen to know it and wishes to use it in a proof nonetheless should probably state explicitly that they are using it (although this situation is unlikely to appear in any marking schemes as it is very likely not the kind of answer that the person writing the marking scheme is anticipating).

To summarize, it may be required if it is used to demonstrate the students' understanding of induction as a principle/proof method, if it is relevant to the metamathematical material being tested, if strict formatting guidelines must be followed for some reason, or if students are not expected to know it or learn it in the course at hand but are allowed to use it if they happen to already understand it. Outside of these situations I don't see why students should be required to state its use explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Peano's axioms without the axiom  of induction has some models that do not correspond to the natural numbers that we have in our minds. In order to prove that every natural number $n$ other than $0$ is the successor of some other natural number $k$, i.e., for all $n\ne0$ there exists $k$ such that $S(k)=n$, we must harness the axiom of induction. Think of $k$ as $n-1$.

Consider the model ${\bf N}_\text{strange}$ of Peano's axioms without induction that looks like $$\{0,1,2,3,\ldots, \omega, \omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3
\ldots \}$$ This system satisfies the Peano axioms without induction, although I am not going to digress and give details (use your intuition). In this system, $\omega$ is not the successor of anything. That this is possible is hardly surprising, because we need the axiom of induction to prove that every number other than $0$ has a predecessor.

So why do we want high school students learning about induction to chat "*by mathematical induction blah blah blah*? This is a tricky question. But under the hood, given a proposition $H(n)$  and showing (i) that the base case is true and (ii)  $H_k\implies H_{k+1}$ is **not** sufficient to deduce $H(k)$ for all $k$ in ${\bf N}_\text{strange}$. The truthiness of $H$ would not extend to $\omega$. One justification for the required chat invoking induction is "mathematical honesty," although I don't think this will be appreciated at scale!

Comment: In ${\bf N}_\text{strange}$, what number is immediately before $\omega$?

Comment: @Dan There is not one, and I state this explicitly. This is the whole point. This is possible if we do not have induction.

Comment: Is ${\bf N}_\text{strange}$ really "***the*** model of Peano's axioms without induction" or just "***a*** model that satisfies Peano's axioms without induction"?

Comment: @Stef It might be more clear if I had written "Consider the *following* model..." There are many other models of PA without the axiom of induction besides this one that I am referring to as ${\bf N}_\text{strange}$.

Comment: @Raciquel This is interesting! I like to use $\omega$ without formally calling it "infinity." It gets young imaginations churning and thinking about the transfinite realm. The idea is the $\omega>n$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. One concern I have about using the complex imaginary unit is that the system will not be closed under multiplication, and you have to be careful with the total ordering

Answer (score 3):

Let's not overlook an obvious application of induction is to turn it around and go from general to specific.

Let's say we have established $H(1)$ and that $H(k+1)$ follows from $H(k)$ and we are perfectly content with whatever algebra and logic was involved to establish this. But we simply refuse to recognize or accept induction as method of proof. We just refuse to chant "*by induction, $H(n)$ is true for all $n\in{\bf N}$.*"

Now then, how would we actually write down a proof of $H(10,000)$? Well, we would start our proof by establishing $H(2)$, then we would continue writing by establishing $H(3)$, etc. Eventually we would have written down a very long, boring and stupid proof that establishes $H(10,000)$. If only we not so stubborn, and were willing to invoke induction to **first** conclude $H(n)$ is true for all $n\in{\bf N}$, and *then* go from general to specific: apply the validity of $H(n)$ for all $n\in{\bf N}$ to the specific case $n=10,000$.

In a similar vein, how can we establish $$\sum_{n=1}^{10,000} n^2 = 333383335000$$ if we refuse to accept induction as a method of proof?

No problem. We just have a symbolic computational system like Wolfram perform the sum. Perhaps for the first $N=10,000$ terms the system is actually doing the addition by brute force. But at higher values of $N$, the system is smart enough to "cheat" and skip the onerous addition, and instead substitute $N$ into the formula $\frac{N(N + 1)(2N + 1)}{6}$. So again, induction is being used to go from general to specific. The general result is the statement
$$H(N):\ \sum_{n=1}^N n^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$$ which is established by induction, and we go to the specific case by substituting a numerical value into the formula.

Answer (score 3):

To be a proof, an argument *needs to be explicit about the logical structure*.  An induction proof won't be any different.  Take a very standard task like: such as showing that, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n
$$
(i.e., that the rational function on the left is the polynomial on the right).

**Answer 1:** Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be given. We  compute
$$
 (1 - x)(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n) = 
  (1 - x) + (x - x^2) + \cdots + (x^n - x^{n+1})
$$
Rebracketing the rhs we get
$$
  1 + (-x + x) + (-x^2 + x^2) + \cdots + (-x^n + x^n) - x^{n+1} = 1 - x^{n+1}
$$
and so
$$
  (1 - x)(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n) = 1 - x^{n+1}
$$
Dividing both sides by $1-x$ gives the identity we wanted for this $n$.
As $n\in \mathbb{N}$ was arbitrary, the identity holds for all $n$.

*Comments:* I picked this example because it is a standard
school induction exercise, but this isn't a proof by induction.
The logical structure is different.  (Though it is the same structure you see in $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs from calculus class. A  weird thing to university level instructors is that some students think that "proofs" are "proof by induction" when they arrive, and then struggle with simpler direct proofs like this one.)

**Answer 2:** The proof is by induction on $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The base case is $n=0$. We  verify it directly:
$$
\frac{1 - x^{0 + 1}}{1 - x} = \frac{1 - x}{1 - x} = 1
$$
Now we suppose that, for some $n\ge 0$,
$$
\frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n
$$
Consider now the sum
$$
1 + x + \cdots + x^n + x^{n+1}
$$
By the induction hypothesis, this is equal to
$$
\frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x} + x^{n+1} = 
\frac{1 - x^{n+1} + (1 - x)x^{n+1}}{1-x} = 
\frac{1 - x^{n+1} +  x^{n+1} - x^{n+2}}{1-x} =
\frac{1- x^{(n+1) + 1}}{1-x}
$$
Hence the induction hypothesis implies that the identity holds for $n+1$.  This closes the induction, and so we conclude that the identity holds for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

*Comments:* Whether a version of this  argument uses the specific template I have (or some other one), it would need to say that induction is being used, what the parameter is, what the IH is and so on. By  itself, the final computation is pretty meaningless. Even a very terse version like:
*we have $\frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x} + x^{n+1} = \frac{1 - x^{n+2}}{1-x}$ so the identity holds for all $n$ by induction* is clear about the logical structure.

You also ask:

> If a proof by induction has to explicitly refer to the principle of
> mathematical induction, then do proofs using the pigeonhole principle
> have to explicitly refer to the pigeonhole principle? Do proofs by
> contradiction have to explicitly refer to the principle of proof by
> contradiction (if there is such a thing)?

The answer is (obviously?) "yes" to both of these questions.  Much like with induction, there is even a standard template for proofs by contradiction, which begins: "*Suppose, for a contradiction, that ...*"

Comment: The two proofs are very similar, the main difference being that in the second proof the telescoping happens only with one pair of terms whereas with the first it happens with a whole series of pairs at once, something that, strictly speaking, can only be justified by an appeal to induction. (This essentially reproduces the second proof.) "Logical structure" can be hard to pin down. Certain manipulations permitted to students may have a lot of logical structure hidden inside. What are the rules that determine when such structure has to be made explicit?

Comment: @WillOrrick: In the first proof, once $n$ is fixed, the coefficients of a polynomial multiplication are determined by a formula, which is what I used and also would expect high school students to know. You don’t need induction there. 

I think your other question is sort of losing the big picture. A proof needs to state a hypothesis, state a conclusion, have a sequence of steps going from the hypothesis to the conclusion, and then justify the steps. The question is asking whether students can just skip everything except for the steps. They can’t. It’s more basic than detail in calculation.

Comment: I agree that students should be taught to communicate their reasoning clearly and not leave it to the instructor to fill in the logic joining the steps of a proof together. But I think it would helpful to students to be up front about the game we're playing with them. We allow them to assume some things as black boxes, but require them to justify others, and we expect them to figure out which is which with only fragmentary guidance. (Unless we're teaching formal logic with axioms, in which case each step must be justified.) In a practical setting proving a result to someone means convincing...

Comment: ...them that it follows from things they already believe. Both students and instructor come in already believing many things. In this example those beliefs include that $n$-fold sums are well-defined without parentheses to indicate the order of evaluation, that the distributive law applies to $n$-fold sums, that $n$-fold sums may be reparenthesized freely, that $a+0+0+\ldots+0=a$ (with $n$ zero terms). Since addition is usually defined as a binary operation, extension of the basic properties of addition to these $n$-fold situations requires proof, and induction is the essential tool in...

Comment: ...all these proofs. I don't think any of these can be obtained without induction.

Comment: Your answer is very nice, and it has education value. The contrast between Answer 1 and Answer 2 is valuable.  But Will Orrick has a valid point. Answer 1 is using induction in subtle ways. For example, how do with know that $x\cdot x^n=x^{n+1}$ without induction. In fact to even *define* $x^n$ for a generic $n$ requires induction. Yes, we can define $x^{100}$ without induction, but without induction we can speak of $x^n$ only when $n$ is a specific integer.

Comment: I think there may be a 'context' problem with the specific chosen example: while the rational function and the polynomial are equal as elements of $k(X)$, they are not equal as functions from (subsets of) $k$ to $k$, so one should be careful. Also, the closing remark about proofs by contradiction seems to not distinguish those from proofs of negation. Lastly, @user52817 comment may be related to the fact that some theories lack enough induction to prove exponentiation is total, for example Robinson arithmetic

Comment: @ac15 Yes, your comment about Robinson Arithmetic is precisely what I have in mind. It is essentially Peano without induction. RA has simple models where exponentiation is not total. In other words, we need induction to define $x^n$. It gets to be unnerving when we start to realize how often we are using induction in "every day math" without being aware of it!

Comment: I am going to reiterate that you are all losing the LO, which is a first encounter with informal proofs that go from premises to conclusions.  It is not formal logic and it is not developing, from first principles, things students have been taught, such as "a finite sum of zeros is zero" or what the coefficient of $x^k$ is in $(a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n)(b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_mx^m)$.  Having watched some disasters, the issue is that the foundational stuff is easy but tedious *if you have a mature approach*, but it is not a good way to develop a mature approach.

Comment: Agreed about not starting with a formal approach. I think the proof below, maybe with a few extra words to explain the algebra, is clear about its reasoning:
\begin{align}
1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n &= \frac{1-x}{1-x}+\frac{x-x^2}{1-x}+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n\\
&=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x}+\frac{x^2-x^3}{1-x}+x^3+\ldots+x^n\\
&=\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}+\frac{x^3-x^4}{1-x}+\ldots+x^n\\
\end{align}
Repeating this process over and over, the $n$th line would be
$$
\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}+\frac{x^n-x^{n+1}}{1-x},
$$
which equals
$$
\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.
$$

Comment: It's probably unclear what point I was trying to make with my last comment. The proof there (1) uses very similar reasoning to your proof 1 (algebraic manipulation of n-fold sums), but (2) implements the essential idea of your inductive proof 2. And yet (3) it never mentions the word induction and is not set up as a standard inductive proof. I would say, however, (without having tested it in the real world) that (4) this proof is understandable and fully convincing to a person sufficient skilled in algebra to follow the steps, even if they've never heard of induction.

Comment: @Louis i would say fondational stuff is anything but easy

Comment: @WillOrrick induction/recursion is called in "Repeating this process over and over", even if not by name

Comment: @ac15 Yes, that point was made earlier in this comment thread. I considered repeating it in my later comment, but decided against it. What I've been trying to say is that if being "explicit about the logical structure" means communicating one's ideas clearly at a level appropriate to the reader and including appropriate detail given the educational context, I'm all for it. If it means classifying different proofs according to some inherent logical structure, well that's much more fraught.

Answer (score 2):

From a traditional standpoint in teaching high school math, clarity and pedagogy are paramount. A proof by induction traditionally includes an explicit reference to the principle of mathematical induction to ensure that students understand not just the mechanics of the proof but also the underlying logical framework that validates the approach. While technically it may be sufficient to show that the base case holds and the inductive step follows (Hk ⟹ Hk+1), explicitly stating that one is using the principle of mathematical induction reinforces the method and its formal structure, which is crucial for educational purposes.

Regarding other principles like the pigeonhole principle or proof by contradiction, traditionally, it is also considered good practice to name the principle being used. This practice helps students to distinguish between various proof techniques and understand their applications. However, as with the principle of mathematical induction, it may not always be necessary to name the principle as long as the logical structure of the proof is clear and correct.

In educational settings, it is often beneficial to be explicit about these principles to aid learning, even if, in professional mathematics, such explicit references may sometimes be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a proof by induction have to explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction?

There's no obligation of course, but it seems to be good pedagogy, especially at [ealy(er) stages](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/), to ask for and foster explicitness on argumentation. On the matter of induction specifically, one could do wonders by discussing *the different forms* of induction:

- 'Sucessor induction', the best known, that holds in the natural numbers;
- 'Well-ordered induction', that also holds in, say, $\omega+\omega$, $\omega + \omega + \omega$,..., with these lacking 'sucessor induction' [as a previous answer noted](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/27195/15843), but otherwise being models for sucessor-addition-multiplication arithmetic;
- '[Well-founded induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation)', (sometimes called either 'weak' or 'strong' [!] induction in the context of the naturals) that holds for binary strings $2^{<\omega}$ ordered by the substring relation, or for [well-formed formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) ordered by the subformula relation, each of these *not* being well-orders

Of course each case implies the next, and the examples show the implications are not reversible. The last one's likely to be more interesting/useful to students with interests in computing sciences, but really, just talk to them about these things

> Do proofs by contradiction have to explicitly refer to the principle of proof by contradiction (if there is such a thing)?

Yes, please, let's try to teach people that [proofs of negations are not the same thing as proofs by contradiction](https://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/)

Answer (score -3):

The Principle of Mathematical Induction states:

$\forall P\subset N:[0 \in P \land \forall x\in P: [S(x) \in P] \implies P=N]$

Where $S$ is the successor function on $N$.

IMHO high-school students in North America will not be able to grasp the meaning of this statement, never mind apply it in proofs. I'm guessing most high-school teachers there won't understand it either.

**EDIT**

This is not to say that proof by induction should not be taught in high schools. Just don't dwell on the above axiom as seems to be suggested here. A formalized approach, even if translated into words, will only create confusion at that level. If students cannot recall the exact wording of the axiom, they may think the cannot do proof by induction.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but just FYI that in the USA, it's not uncommon to see induction covered in a honors precalculus class. See, for example, the popular textbook by [Larson](https://www.spps.org/cms/lib010/MN01910242/Centricity/Domain/6062/PreCalculus%20Text.pdf).

Comment: -1 That's the prototype of a straw man argument. You take a rather natural concept, write it down in the very abstract language of formal logic, and then claim that high schoolers weren't able to understand the concept itself (rather than the language in which you wrote it down). This is like writing a cook book with all the recipes formulated as algorithms in pseudo code, to then claim that most people weren't able to cook.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck: *write it down in the very abstract language of formal logic* --- And not correctly either. $0 \in N$ should be $0 \in P.$

Comment: @JochenGlueck It simply isn't necessary to "explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction" in every proof by induction.

Comment: @JustinSkycak I cover induction in my college algebra class (which is sort-of/kind-of the first semester of a year long precalculus sequence).  For a lot of my students, it is their favorite part of the class (assuming evaluations can be believed...).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I took several undergrad pure math courses that required proofs by induction. I don't recall any mention of a principle of mathematical induction as an axiom.  I know that high-school students have a hard time with PBI. I don't think requiring an explicit citation of the PMI would help matters.

Comment: I don't feel this answers the question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The question was. "Does a proof by induction have to explicitly refer to the principle of mathematical induction?" I have argued to contrary. PBI is difficult enough for students without having to also introduce axiomatic number theory.